# Specify external content type lookup for deployable list?

Tags: 2010, bcs, custom-list

I have a `ListTemplate` which is being deployed with Visual Studio.

Is it possible to make a reference from this template to an external content type that runs on the farm? Or must I manually add these columns within the SharePoint UI?

I've saved the list as a template, and looking at the relevant `<Field>` tags in the extracted `manifest.xml` gives me:

```
<Field Type="BusinessData"
    DisplayName="Staff ID"
    Required="FALSE"
    ID="{c56a95c8-b5f4-4e83-8eb9-eb75743f8837}"
    SourceID="{6db0b01d-3673-435d-93d6-c7d7d3757185}"
    StaticName="Staff_x0020_ID"
    BaseRenderingType="Text"
    Name="Staff_x0020_ID"
    ColName="nvarchar12"
    RowOrdinal="0"
    SystemInstance="People"
    EntityNamespace="People"
    EntityName="Staff"
    BdcField="StaffID"
    Profile="/_layouts/ActionRedirect.aspx?EntityNamespace=Mwe%2ESharePoint%2EStaffInfo%2EPeople&amp;EntityName=Staff&amp;LOBSystemInstanceName=People&amp;ItemID="
    HasActions="True"
    SecondaryFieldBdcNames="(trim)"
    RelatedField="Staff_ID"
    SecondaryFieldWssNames="(trim)"
    RelatedFieldBDCField=""
    RelatedFieldWssStaticName="Staff_ID"
    SecondaryFieldsWssStaticNames="(trim)"
    AddFieldOption="AddToDefaultContentType, AddFieldToDefaultView"
    Version="1"/>


<Field Type="Note"
    DisplayName="Staff_ID"
    Hidden="TRUE"
    ReadOnly="TRUE"
    BdcField="Staff_ID"
    ID="{26213047-a755-412f-98f5-6c2492c863b6}"
    SourceID="{6db0b01d-3673-435d-93d6-c7d7d3757185}"
    StaticName="Staff_ID"
    Name="Staff_ID"
    ColName="ntext2"
    RowOrdinal="0"/>
```

The problem is, when I try to put this into my List Template's `Elements.xml` in the project/solution it fails with pretty much every one of the attributes in the BusinessData-typed Field.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this question when searching for a solution to a related problem with Caml defined lookup columns that map to bcs entities, so I am leaving this notice hoping it may be useful to future viewers.

Based on [this reference from Microsft forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/249ca2b3-491a-496a-89b9-7c3b83236d54/creating-a-site-column-that-looks-up-an-external-list-causes-error-when-saving-site-as-a-template?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) it would seem that the default schema for caml declarations in SharePoint does not include some of the attribute needed to declare a bcs related lookup.

The above post suggests to modify the wss.xsd file located at c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML - this seems to bypass the errors (on a similar project, we weren't able to deploy the solution and activate the features until this mod was made). That said, I suspect that doing so would put you in an unsupported scenario... also notice that even with this mod I still wasn't able to create a fully functional lookup.

Also notice this post that provides a programmatic approach to the problem: [here](http://tom-dw.blogspot.it/2010/08/sharepoint-2010-use-bcs-lookup-field-in.html). Even in this case though the poster seems to be experiencing random outputs....